# How to find the argument of a complex component?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z=1+i$ and $c=1-i$.

what is the value of $|Arg(Z^C)|$ ?

Using the principle value of $Z^C$ and after simplification I have found out :

$Z^C=exp(ln\sqrt2 +\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}-iln\sqrt2)$  .

$Arg(Z^C)=tan^-1 (\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-ln\sqrt2}{\frac{\pi}{4}+ln\sqrt2})=21.19$

This is how came up with a solution . But my answer doesnt match with the correct answer , can anyone point out the mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does $|\arg z^c|$ mean?

Comment: For argument of $z^c$ you could take arctangent $y/x$ where $z^c = x+i y$.  But if $z^c = e^{x+iy}$, the argument is $y$.

Comment: @Myst1cal Edited !!

Comment: @GEdgar i didnt understand you , can you elaborate it ?

Comment: You computed $z^c$ as $\exp(M)$, say.  Then you took the argument of $M$ instead of the argument of $\exp(M)$.

Comment: @GEdgar i have to take exp(ln\sqrt2-pi/4) as y  instead of taking (ln\sqrt2-pi/4) as y  ?

Comment: @Hoppo $|\arg z^c|\approx 0.7 $

Comment: @Myst1cal i am sorry to say but the answer is wrong . Correct answer given 25.148 . I just want to know  how they got that answer correct ?

Comment: @Hoppo It uses the principal argument probably. If you add $8\pi$ to my answer, you get $25.833$ approximately.

Comment: My answer is $0.4388$ which is $25.14$ degrees.

Comment: @GEdgar YEAH how did you do it with principal argument ? Can you write it in the answer section ?

Answer (score 2):

Note.  If $x,y$ are real, then
$$
e^{x+iy} = e^x e^{iy}
\\
\big|e^{x+iy}\big| = e^x\\
\arg e^{x+iy} = y
$$

In this case,
$$
z^c = \exp\left(\log\sqrt2 + \frac{\pi}{4} + i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\log\sqrt2\right)\right)\\
\arg(z^c) = \frac{\pi}{4}-\log\sqrt2 \approx 0.4388
$$
in degrees,
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\log\sqrt2\right)\frac{180}{\pi} \approx 25.143
$$

Comment: You see i had problem with the basic , i took both real part and imaginary part as mathematics is not my major so i am not that much good with the basics to be honest , i dont know from where i have taken the idea of arc as tan^-1(y/a)

Comment: In fact, $\arg(x+iy) = \arctan(y/x)$ in the first quadrant.